# PDFJS rendering garbage characters in iOS 10.3.x

Tags: pdf.js

I am using pdfjs library to show base64 data as pdf. It is rendering garbage characters for the first time when I invoke render method but start working properly on subsequent call.

Comment: What is your code so far? What is the expected output, and what happens instead? What are "garbage" characters?

Comment: I am just trying to open a base64 by using pdfjs. It is working fine for all iOS version but 10.3.3. It is showing '?' instead of letters.